# Display user's input in 2 different places using PHP

Tags: php, html, input

```
<input id="myID" name="inputName" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder" maxlength="16">

<h3><?php echo $_POST['MCusername']; ?><h3>
```

What I was really looking for is to display whatever is typed into the input tag, instantly got put into the h3 tag.

Sorry, I'm still new to PHP .

Comment: Try using JS for this! You're trying to do something entirely on the client side.

Comment: use a conditional `isset()` or `!empty()` if you want to do this in pure PHP and just copy the POST array while assigned to a variable. Easy as pie really.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fetoasxc/

Comment: Plus, your named attribute (and ID) doesn't even match your POST array

Comment: @Fred -ii- It's completely impossible to do this in PHP, or at the very least, it's unnecessary, because PHP works server-side and that would mean the user has to send data to the server and request data every time he presses something in that input field. I guess you just didn't understand what he wanted though.

Comment: @AndrosRex No it isn't impossible. If they're looking for "instantly" as a user types it in, sure I'll agree there. But it's not "impossible" in pure PHP.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Hmm, you meant when the user submits the input, I suppose. Then yeah, you're right that it's possible and you have to use isset() to check if it has been submitted or not.

Comment: @AndrosRex Exactly. The question's a bit unclear though as they didn't tag as javascript/jquery and made no mention of it. So, maybe they don't know what they're looking for, or the terminologies. We can only offer them what we can in comments/answers ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone, I got it working. I didn't really know what I was doing at first, I've ended up using Jquery and saved myself the headache getting it working with PHP.

Comment: @Josh You don't need to include a whole library for this little job, though. Also, the jQuery solution fires a query every time the text is changed without the need for that. Just pointing that out~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below example uses JQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#myID" ).keyup(function() {
          $("#typedID").html( $(this).val() );
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="myID" name="inputName" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder" maxlength="16">

<h3 id="typedID"><h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript for this. Your PHP would have to be something like this (crudely):

```
<input id="myID" name="inputName" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder" maxlength="16" onchange="updateh3()" onkeyup="updateh3()">

<h3 id="myh3"><h3>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var h3 = document.getElementById('myh3');
    function updateh3(ev) {
        h3.innerHTML = ev.target.value;
    }

</script>
```